# Do I want to create a native module or a native UI component?

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native

I have a Swift class that's mostly used like a React Native module. The module uses an unseen WKWebView to function, and occasionally I'll assign that WKWebView as a subview in my ViewController to debug my implementation, like this:

```
swiftClass.webView.frame = self.view.frame
self.view.addSubview(swiftClass.webView)
```

What's the easiest way to bridge this functionality over to React Native? It seems like I'm sitting in between a module and a UI component. If I write it as a UI component, how can I call the methods of the class? If I write it as a module, how can I add it to my view hierarchy?

Should I just rewrite the module in React Native using the WebView? I'm hesitant to do so because the RN implementation uses UIWebView, which is slower than WKWebView, and I don't want to pollute the JS thread and potentially cause any slowdowns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of these approaches could work but have different tradeoffs. I'll talk about the tradeoffs and nuances, and hopefully that will help you choose an approach that works well for your needs.

#### As a UI component

Bridged UI components are responsible for creating a view that React Native inserts into the native view hierarchy. When your React component is unmounted, the corresponding native view is removed from the view hierarchy and released.

So one question is: does it make sense to give your API the life cycle of a React component?

Also, on iOS, React Native actually asks your bridged view manager for one extra instance of the view. For example, if you have three bridged components in your JS, React Native will create four instances of your native view. The reason for the extra view is that it serves as a template; when you unset a bridged component's prop from JS and React Native needs to restore the native view's property to its default value, it uses the template view to figure out that default value.

#### As a bridge module

Bridge modules don't have as close of a relationship to the native view hierarchy, and they are initialized once per `RCTBridge` instance that you create (most applications have just one bridge).

Is your API more global in nature and live for the duration of your application? Then it often makes sense to expose it as a bridge module that is independent of the React component hierarchy.

As for the `WKWebView`, it's probably best to add it outside of the React Native view hierarchy. Using native APIs to modify parts of the view hierarchy owned by React Native is an abstraction violation and could break. So, I recommend either inserting the `WKWebView` outside of the React Native view hierarchy (ex: getting the `UIWindow` with `RCTKeyWindow()`) or defining a UI component instead of a bridge module and adding the `WKWebView` as a subview of an empty view when its needed.

#### In JS using RN's WebView

In the long run, this should be the best approach for mobile libraries of the future, because of the superior development workflow and cross-platform benefits of pure JS. But if the current WebView implementations don't meet your needs, you should write your own native UI component or module.

Comment: How can I call functions of the class if I write a UIComponent?

Comment: Make the UIComponent be a native module as well and then from JS you can call JS static methods and pass in the node handle / React tag (same thing) from JS to native.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up creating a bridge module and adding these functions:

```
  @objc func showView() {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{
      let rootVC = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate!.window!!.rootViewController!
      self.webView.frame = rootVC.view.frame
      rootVC.view.addSubview(self.webView)
    })

  }

  @objc func hideView() {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{
      self.webView.removeFromSuperview()
    })

  }
```

Since I'm only calling these in debugging situations, it's been sufficient. I'll probably rewrite them to use RN's WebView eventually, but no need to reinvent the wheel for now.